# How to load a list of objects from a request?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im having troubles with my first request which response is an array of objects and i need help

The model class is:

```
    import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

List<Event> eventFromJson(String str) => List<Event>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Event.fromJson(x)));

String eventToJson(List<Event> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Event {
    Event({
        required this.id,
        required this.state,
        required this.province,
        required this.city,
        required this.latitude,
        required this.longitude,
        required this.startDate,
        required this.endDate,
        required this.openDoors,
        required this.startEventHour,
        required this.endDateHour,
        required this.nameEvent,
        required this.artistname,
        required this.poster,
        required this.enclosure,
        required this.eventType,
    });

    String id;
    String state;
    String province;
    String city;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
    String openDoors;
    String startEventHour;
    String endDateHour;
    String nameEvent;
    String artistname;
    String poster;
    String enclosure;
    String eventType;

    
    factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
        id: json["id"],
        state: json["state"],
        province: json["province"],
        city: json["city"],
        latitude: json["latitude"],
        longitude: json["longitude"],
        startDate: json["startDate"],
        endDate: json["endDate"],
        openDoors: json["openDoors"],
        startEventHour: json["startEventHour"],
        endDateHour: json["endDateHour"],
        nameEvent: json["nameEvent"],
        artistname: json["artistname"],
        poster: json["poster"],
        enclosure: json["enclosure"],
        eventType: json["eventType"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "state": state,
        "province": province,
        "city": city,
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
        "startDate": startDate,
        "endDate": endDate,
        "openDoors": openDoors,
        "startEventHour": startEventHour,
        "endDateHour": endDateHour,
        "nameEvent": nameEvent,
        "artistname": artistname,
        "poster": poster,
        "enclosure": enclosure,
        "eventType": eventType,
    };
}
```

The class where im doing the request is:

```
class MockEventRepository extends EventRepository{

  String _url = 'nevermind';
  Dio _dio =  Dio();
  
  @override
  Future<Event?> getEvent() {

    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
  Future<List<Event>> getEvents({bool refresh = false})async{
    List<Event> events = <Event>[];
    try{
        Response response   = await _dio.get(_url); 
        //Event event = Event.fromJson(response.data);
        String decodedData = json.decode(response.data);
        print(decodedData);
        
         return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () =>events);
         }on DioError catch(e){
           print(e);
           return [];
         }
  }

 
}
```

I can't read the list of 3 events which url gives me and this is the error:

List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

So if u can help me i would be very grateful

Comment: What does `print(decodedData)` output? Where does your code fail? Could you provide more information?

Comment: @mddg the error is on json.decode(response.data); and here  Event event = Event.fromJson(response.data); so i can't see what is the print output

Answer (score 0):

After you map each element from your response you should use the method .toList().

This is how your code should look like:

```
List<Event> eventFromJson(String str) => List<Event>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Event.fromJson(x)).toList());
```

Comment: but how can i use this, is already on my model